# javascript : how to find the parent node given the innerhtml

Tags: javascript

Here is my HTML snippet.

```
<div id='advanced'>
  <a id='javscript'>testing</a>
</div>
```

I need to find the parent node given the innerhtml testing.

Comment: Hi

Here is my HTML snippet.
<div id='advanced'>
<a id='javscript'>testing</a>
</div>

I need to find the parent node given the innerhtml testing.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Any solution is going to be extremely inefficient, requiring looping through every node and checking its innerHTML string until you reach a matching node.  Whatever it is, there's probably a better way.

Comment: It's possible but complicated, e.g. through some regex. The real question is why are you in this situation and not in something saner?

Comment: Is there a larger framework consideration that is driving this question? I can't offhand see too many instances where knowing the element contents would drive a search of the DOM. Is this something along the lines of a custom list of content or area that will get updated with any frequency? Can you please provide more context for this question?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you may want to consider re-thinking whatever it is you're trying to achieve. Anyway, if you need to do just one lookup then you just need to iterate over each node in the DOM tree and test your string against the text content. If you need to do it multiple times then this will get very slow. So a possible solution is this: loop over the DOM  and put the innerHTML into a hash, with the text as the key (field) and the parent node as the value. Then for any text you can test against the hash, returning the parent node if it exists. **But** - don't just bang in every innerHTML for every node - this will result in a large object. If it's just text nodes you're after then only stick these into your hash.

Comment: This is the solution to this problem !!! a parse over the tree. Now implementation just depends on how efficient one writes it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider going with a library, specifically jQuery.
It would make this type of search very easy for you.
This should work:
http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Yes, jQuery makes it very easy to do a very inefficient search... :)

Comment: Don't hate the player, hate the game :)